# What Is The Optimal Way To Select Rows From Last 7 Days?

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

What's the best way to select only those rows from the table that have been created in last 7 days?

There are dozens of time and date functions in MySQL and I'm a little bit confused about what's the easiest way to do this.

For the sake of this question, assume that you have a table called "my_table" and it contains a row "created_at" which is a DATETIME.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ...
```

What would you fill in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Well, there are several ways to do this.  But if you are using a language to build your query, that will change some things.

Comment: @brandon, Not really, you should be using the database to do this, not the app layer.

Comment: So many ways to do the same thing. SO community rox!

Comment: @Byron: Yeah, as does MySQL, although as Richard says, *wow* what a dizzying array of date/time functions. :-)

Comment: @Brandon Hansen: I am actually using Zend Framework and its components (Zend_Db_Table, Zend_Db) to create sql queries but that doesn't change things. You can very well just take a where object and concatenate a string like ' AND field = 5' to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at) <= 7;
```

I like it because it reads: "Where the Difference in Date between Now and when it was created is at most 7 (days)." in my own head

Comment: Hey I like this :) It's very simple and clean :)

Comment: @Drew .. i maybe wrong here .. but wont that query first convert all created_at records and  match afterwards ? isnt that a overhead then doing the match the other way around?

Comment: @Sab: I suspect you're right, especially if `created_at` has an index (and it does, right Richard?). It certainly makes life harder for the optimizer, but would need to benchmark to see whether it overcomes it.

Comment: I haven't looked up the function yet, but be careful with simply saying "older than 7 days from now" because if it's 1 in the afternoon, many of these types of functions only return results that are from the last `7 * 24 hours` thus leaving out any records from that first day BEFORE 1 PM. That's why my answer uses `DATE()` around any timestamp references

Comment: created_at doesn't have index actually because it's not used very much, I use it in a where clause only on a single page.

Comment: @Anthony: According to the docs, it only uses the date portion, so it shouldn't do what you fear it might. 

That particular wad of SQL is just the cleanest way I can write the code. I'm not sure if it's the best for the optimizer. ^^;;

Answer (score 12):

```
...WHERE created_at >= Date_Add(now(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

This is my preferred way because it's so...clear. But `ADDDATE` is fine too (and you can use the `INTERVAL` form with that for clarity as well; its default is days so you see people leaving it off). You *don't* want to do a calculation on `created_at` and compare it to `now()` because that requires the computation on `created_at` on each row (assuming MySQL doesn't optimise it out), whereas modifying `now()` and comparing to an unmodified `created_at` means MySQL does that bit once and uses the result when comparing against rows, not to mention indexes.

Comment: Wow, can't believe no one noticed the missing underscore in `Date_Add`. I've ... *added* ... it. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

...... WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)

hopefully that will help

Answer (score 2):

```
 WHERE  ADDDATE(datefield, 7) > NOW();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE DATE(created_at) >= SUBDATE(DATE(NOW()), 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.datefield > sysdate - 7